# Mentioning resolved illness to statement of purpose?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I had hyperthyroidism which is now resolved. It didn't affected my performance.

Do I have anything to gain if I mention on my SOP that this condition caused me mental symptoms that made it harder for me to study - and despite that I did well?

Comment: I doubt it. They are interested in you, not in who you would have been if you hadn't been ill. (Because from your question I assume the underlying thing you want to say is "I performed well being ill, imagine how I would have performed if I had been healthy".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't put it in writing as it is too easy to misinterpret. If someone thinks that the condition might return it won't work in your favor. Other people have situations that make it hard to study also, medical and otherwise.

I would be less concerned with mentioning it in an interview if it would be a natural part of the conversation, but even then, will require explanation and possible misinterpretation.

Represent yourself as a hard worker who gets things done and performs at a high level. The rest is unimportant.